# loop through json and html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am learning to code and for a challenge I need to get info about a number of twitch channels and update channel info and status if it is streaming live or not. Due to Twitch API constraints I am calling an endpoint to get channel Info and then call another endpoint to see which channel is streaming live and which is not.

Now what I want to do is, loop through the `streamsJson`, and check if a channel ID matches onee of my channels and update the status to live and I need your help for this.

```js
$("document").ready(function() {

  var getUserInfo = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users/?login=ESL_SC2&login=freecodecamp&login=OgamingSC2&login=cretetion&login=storbeck&login=habathcx&login=RobotCaleb&login=noobs2ninjas",
    contentType: ('application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'),
    crossDomain: true,
    headers: {
      "Client-ID": "5k4g3q59o69v6p9tudn39v50ro1mux",
    },
    dataType: "json",
    error: function() {
      console.log("Users call failed");
    },
    success: function(usersJson) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(usersJson, null, 2));
      var getUserStatus = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams/?channel=user_login=ESL_SC2&user_login=freecodecamp&user_login=OgamingSC2&user_login=cretetion&user_login=storbeck&user_login=habathcx&user_login=RobotCaleb&user_login=noobs2ninjas&stream_type=all",
        contenType: ('application/x-www-form-irlencoded; charset=UTF-8'),
        crossDomain: true,
        headers: {
          "Client-ID": "5k4g3q59o69v6p9tudn39v50ro1mux",
        },
        dataType: "json",
        error: function() {
          console.log("Streams call failed");
        },
        success: function(streamsJson) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(streamsJson, null, 2));

          var jsonUsers = usersJson.data;
          // console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonUsers, null, 2));
          // console.log(jsonUsers[0].profile_image_url);

          // channel N° 1
          $("#img-holder1 > img").attr("src", jsonUsers[0].profile_image_url);
          $(".channelInfo1").attr("id", jsonUsers[0].id);
          $(".channelInfo1 > h3").text(jsonUsers[0].display_name);

          // channel N° 2
          $("#img-holder2 > img").attr("src", jsonUsers[1].profile_image_url);
          $(".channelInfo2").attr("id", jsonUsers[1].id);
          $(".channelInfo2 > h3").text(jsonUsers[1].display_name);

          // channel N° 3
          $("#img-holder3 > img").attr("src", jsonUsers[2].profile_image_url);
          $(".channelInfo3").attr("id", jsonUsers[2].id);
          $(".channelInfo3 > h3").text(jsonUsers[2].display_name);

          // channel N° 4
          $("#img-holder4 > img").attr("src", jsonUsers[3].profile_image_url);
          $(".channelInfo4").attr("id", jsonUsers[3].id);
          $(".channelInfo4 > h3").text(jsonUsers[3].display_name);

          // channel N° 5
          $("#img-holder5 > img").attr("src", jsonUsers[4].profile_image_url);
          $(".channelInfo5").attr("id", jsonUsers[4].id);
          $(".channelInfo5 > h3").text(jsonUsers[4].display_name);

          // channel N° 6
          $("#img-holder6 > img").attr("src", jsonUsers[5].profile_image_url);
          $(".channelInfo6").attr("id", jsonUsers[5].id);
          $(".channelInfo6 > h3").text(jsonUsers[5].display_name);

          // channel N° 7
          $("#img-holder7 > img").attr("src", jsonUsers[6].profile_image_url);
          $(".channelInfo7").attr("id", jsonUsers[6].id);
          $(".channelInfo7 > h3").text(jsonUsers[6].display_name);

          // channel N° 8
          $("#img-holder8 > img").attr("src", jsonUsers[7].profile_image_url);
          $(".channelInfo8").attr("id", jsonUsers[7].id);
          $(".channelInfo8 > h3").text(jsonUsers[7].display_name);

          var jsonStreams = streamsJson.data;
          console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonStreams, null, 2));
        },
      });
    },
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

https://codepen.io/HacNass/full/MVjBRq/

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: But what is your question?

Comment: I want loop through the second endpoint and check if `jsonStreams[0].id` exists in my html channels' IDs and update that channel status to Live.

Comment: Not much is going to happen without any HTML...